# hashmap cache in servlet

Tags: java, caching, servlets, hashmap

I am trying to implement a servlet for GPS monitoring and trying create simple cache, because i think that it will be faster then `SQL` request for every Http Request. simple scheme:

in the `init()` method, i reads one point for each vehicle into `HashMap` (vehicle id = key, location in json = value) . after that, some request try to read this points and some request try to update (one vehicle update one item). Of course I want to minimize synchronization so i read javadoc :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

If I am right, there is no any synchronization in my task, because i do only "not a structural modification == changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains)". is it a correct statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConcurrentHashMap it doesn't use synchronization by locks, but by atomic operations.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong.  Adding an item to the hash map is a structural modification (and to implement a cache you must add items at some point).

Use java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: but if there is no adding (apart from in init() which do in single-thread) but only modifying, still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two types of request:

- Read from cache
- Write to cache (to update the value)

In this case, you may potentially try to write to the same map twice at the same time, which is what the docs are referring to.

If all requests go through the same piece of code (e.g. an update method which can only be called from one thread) you will not need synchronisation.

If your system is multi-threaded and you have more than one thread or piece of code that writes to the map, you will need to externally synchronise your map or use a ConcurrentHashMap.

---

For clarity, the reason you need synchronisation is that if you have two threads both trying to update the a JSON value for the same key, who wins? This is either left up to chance or causes exceptions or, worse, buggy behaviour.

Any time you modify the same element from two threads, you need to synchronise on that code or, better still, use a thread-safe version of the data structure if that is applicable.

Comment: one piece of code (one method), multi-thread, but different threads updates different elements. Then what?

Comment: You shouldn't think about 'modifying' or 'updating' an element, think that you are writing a value to that place in the map and replacing the previous one. So yes, you will require synchronisation. Only reading elements does not require synchronisation

Answer (score 0):

if all the entries are read into hashmap in `init()` and then only read/modified - then yes, all the other threads *theoretically* do not need to sync, though some problems might arise due to threads caching values, so `ConcurrentHashMap` would be better.

perhaps rather than implementing cache yourself, use a [simple implementation found in Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: Could you explain, please, exactly what the problem?
related to non-atomic modifying?

Answer (score 0):

Caching is not an easy problem - but it is a known one. Before starting, I would carefully measure wheter you really do have a performance problem, and whether caching actually solve it. You may think it should, and you may be right. You may also be horrendously wrong depending on the situation ("Preemptive optimization is the root of all evil"), so measure.

This said, do not implement a cache yourself, use a library doing it for you. I have personnaly good experience with [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).